# Is there a way to put columns of a table in divs using DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

So what I'm trying to do is make it so that the user can choose which columns of a table to display after it has already been generated. I already have functionality that does this, after the user changes their options it destroys the current table and then reinitializes it with different visibility settings for certain columns. While this works, it's sorta slow and doesn't look as pretty as say, the columns just disappearing. I think if I put the columns in uniquely id'd divs and then edited their css to say `display: none;` using jquery when the user deselects them it would work quicker and more attractively, but I haven't been able to find a way to put the columns in divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I managed to find a function called column().visible that can target columns by index and change their visibility. It works perfectly, and I wasn't able to implement the solutions that others posted.

Also for anyone that comes in later to figure out if you can put the columns in divs, as far as I can tell you cannot, but you might not need to for whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to put the columns in divs.

```
myFunction = function(){
  $('.first').css('display','none')
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjMKyJ)

Comment: what is '.first' in this situation?

Comment: @jz8888 Check out the codepen. 'first' is the class name for the <th> and <td> tags for the column you want to make disappear.

Answer (score 0):

May be a better solution but you could use the CSS `nth-child` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) property and jQuery's `.index()`to identify the column you wish to remove and remove the column from each table row.

Something like this might work (assuming you have a header row containing `<th>` elements):

```
$('table th').on("click", function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $.each('table tr', function() {
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I understand that in 'table th' should be the th of the column that I want to hide, but what should be in the 'table tr' value? I'm running that part as-is and I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in table tr`